# How to get path of Different versions of XCode in command line utility?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, environment-variables, development-environment, xcodebuild

I have install XCode Version 3.2, 4.2, and 5.0 and It has created Directory Structure in Root Directory of MAC as follow

```
## Root ##
 - /Developer
 - /Developer42
 - /Developer50
```

Now When I will check my Environment Variable `PATH`, it will show `/Developer50`

But When I am using Utilities like [iPhoneSim](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim) and [WaxSim](https://github.com/square/WaxSim) I am only getting `/Developer` as my PATH.

In WaxSim, their is argument for environment Variable, But which path should I provide in that? If this is not proper way then How can I set Path to any Developer Directory for XCode?

I just want to run my **app** file **without** launching XCode and with the **Custom iPhone/Simulator** and **Custom SDKs**.

For this I had also refer http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/getting-started-iphone-sdk.html

Here I have referred to ***PROTOTYPE*** section and ***BUILDING AN APPLICATION*** section.

thank for any help...

**EDIT 1**

```
mac-mini:~ neha$ $PATH
  -bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
mac-mini:~ neha$ echo "PATH=$PATH:/Developer:/Developer50" >> ~/.bashrc
mac-mini:~ neha$ $PATH
  -bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
mac-mini:~ neha$ source ~/.bashr
     -bash: /Users/neha/.bashr: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 2**
For WaxSim i am using following command. So what is wrong in this?? I am not able to get `/Developer50` path

```
mac-mini:~ neha$ /DHIREN/waxsim -e PATH="/Developer50/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer50/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" -s 5.0 /DHIREN/TestEnvVar.app
Unknown sdk '5.0'
Available sdks are...
  3.2
  4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok @chrown thanx for your help.

I have found that those utility were using the static path given in ***Build Settings*** so I have deleted the **Other Linker Flags** of those utility and compiled again.

Now I have to set the path for those Linker Flags in my environment variable. So i had used below command.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/<xcode-directory>/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/
```

Then I have used **xcode-select -switch** command to switch my Xcode versions and that was all i have to do... Utility itself will take care of the path..

Answer (score 1):

Open up Terminal.app and type this:

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:/Developer:/Developer42:/Developer50" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Replace/Add to `/Developer:/Developer42:/Developer50` with `/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer42/usr/bin:/Developer50/usr/bin`, adding each path that you want to be in your `PATH`, seperated by a `:`.  Then type:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to source the file.  Restart any open programs/shells that need to use `PATH` and when you run them the next time they will have the updated paths.

Comment: please look the edit portion. I am getting error for setting path.

Comment: Change `source ~/.bashr` to `source ~/.bashrc`, your missing the last `c`

Comment: I am not familiar with waxsim, but there should be a command like flag to specify a location of the SDKs, which I believe is here: `/Developer50/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/SDKs`.  Try running `/DHIREN/waxsim --help` or `/DHIREN/waxsim -h`.

Comment: And, instead of running `$PATH` run `echo $PATH`, if you dont include the echo the terminal thinks your trying to run the variables value as a command.

Comment: ok I am able to set Path but not able to get path to SDK 5.0 path? So exactly which path should i set?

Comment: Not exactly sure, I'd have to google some, but try running `/DHIREN/waxsim --help` or `man /DHIREN/waxsim` and the resulting help text should say how to set the SDK path.

Comment: I tried using help but i am getting error of UNKNOWN SDKs... so i need the exact path of SDK... but anyways thanks for your efforts...

Comment: The SDK path is in: `/Developer50/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/SDKs`, try `/Developer50/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/SDKs/5.0`.

Comment: No such path exists. in iPhoneSimulator.platform i have Developer and in that SDKs/iphonesimulator4.3.sdk

Comment: Hmm, I guess the only thing left to try is reinstalling Xcode 4.2 :/